# What came first. The verb "to bumble" or the insect "bumblebee"

Tags: etymology, verbs

I was thinking one day about this. Not sure which came first, I'm guessing the verb came first but a second opinion would be nice

Comment: This question will be closed for [lack of research](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5459/new-close-reason-include-the-research). But interesting nonetheless!

Comment: The earliest match I could confirm for "bumble" in the Early English Books Online database appears as part of the term _bumble bee_. From Thomas More, "[A Dialoge of Comfort Against Tribulacion](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A07696.0001.001/1:4.17?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=bumble)" (1534/1553): "& yet for the shorte whyle yt we be vpward and a loft, lord how lusty & how proude we be, buzzing aboue busily like as a **bumble bee** flieth about in sommer, neuer ware yt he shall dye in wynter:"

Comment: ...But earlier—in [_The second parte of the confutacion of Tyndals answere..._](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A07694.0001.001/1:2.4?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=humble+bee) (1533)—More refers to the insect as a "humble bee": "...and gape by daye agaynste the sonne, by nyght agaynste the mone, tyll eyther some blynde betle or some holy **humble bee** come flye in at theyr mouthes, and buzze in to theyr brestes an vnholsome hepe of flye blowen errours and motthe eten heresyes."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Google's Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=7&corpus=26&content=bumble%2C%20bumblebee&case_insensitive=on&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cbumble%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BBumble%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbumble%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBUMBLE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cbumblebee%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbumblebee%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBumblebee%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBUMBLEBEE%3B%2Cc0), "bumble" came way before "bumblebee."

Also, here is an article about the origins of the noun bumblebee [by O’Conner and Kellerman at Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2016/09/bumblebee.html) which states that bumble originally only meant "a humming sound"/"to make a humming sound," and later gained the meaning to "move, act, or fly in an awkward way". Once it gained the second meaning, it was essentially inevitable for "bumblebee" to be invented.

Comment: Etymonline is interesting: https://www.etymonline.com/word/bumble-bee

Comment: that's odd, in .de it's called the *Hummel*; whereas *bummeln* may be "to promenade, shop" or more commonly in specific idiomatism "to be slow to catch up, be a drag, looser", whereas *pummel-* is "chubby" as I understand it, whereas *buzz, humm* may be "summen" (hence *Sumse*, kinda insect's pet name), and *bumm, huzz* is--I thought I was going for a yoke, but *bum-sen* really means erratic movement, "to bump", also "bump uglies", a *Bums* could be a crash, and it appears more or less onomatopoetic; *hus-ten* "cough, hiss" too, but *hustellen*, *herstellen*, *heißen* are a different field tho

Comment: also [boom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boom)

Comment: And [Pummelfee](https://google.com/search?q=Pummelfee)

Comment: Since both words are evidenced in materials from the early Sixteenth Century, the Google Ngram results can't address the actual question here properly.  But +1 for the  O’Conner / Kellerman (Grammarphobia) article. I've added the required link / attribution. _Note however that they concede that the jury is out on the precise etymology involved._